# Calculate average (mean) of the column after reactively sort the data in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of the column from a reactive variable.

I have 2 columns on the original data sheet "DN (categorical)" and "Intensity (numerical)". I would like to calculate the mean of "intensity" after filtered by "DN". Blow is my script.

```
DN  Intensity
EX2 72.35579
EX2 66.59401
EX2 64.26114
EX2 81.52641
EX2 68.62764
EX2 74.28244
EX3 123.60344
EX3 123.0854
EX3 119.91794
EX3 122.62172
EX3 111.73214
EX3 126.37246

df1 <-data.frame("DN"=DN, "Intensity"=Intensity)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Volume Calculator"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("Y", "Y",choices=Y, selected = TRUE, multiple = TRUE),
      dateInput("X", "X:",format = "mm/dd/yy")),
    mainPanel(column(5,
                     sliderInput("Time",
                                 "Time:",
                                 min = 1,
                                 max = 60,
                                 value = 30),
                     selectInput("DN", "DN", choices = D1N),
                     
                     column(5,
                            fluidRow(
                              h3("Total"),
                              verbatimTextOutput("Ex1"))
                     ))
              
    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  d<- reactive({
    res <- d1 %>%%>%
      filter(DN == input$DN) %>%
      res})
  
  output$Ex1 <- renderPrint({
    dataset <-d()
    Int <-tapply(dataset[[input$Intensity]],dataset[[input$DN]], mean, na.rm=TRUE)
    D1m <- abs(input$Time)
    results1 <- round(Int*Time, digits=0)
    results1  
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry for the messy codes. I hope this change will make it clear.

Comment: Please post some sample data for `d1`, and definition of `Time` and `Intensity`.  Otherwise, no one can figure out how you are obtaining `input$Time` and `input$Intensity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions does not have all the information. Some values are unknown and some operations are unclear. For eg, no information is shared about `Y` or `input$Intensity`. Also I don't think you need `tapply` here since you are filtering only one `DN` value.

Assuming the data that you have is called `df1` you can try -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Volume Calculator"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("Y", "Y",choices=letters, selected = TRUE, multiple = TRUE),
      dateInput("X", "X:",format = "mm/dd/yy")),
    mainPanel(column(5,
                     sliderInput("Time",
                                 "Time:",
                                 min = 1,
                                 max = 60,
                                 value = 30),
                     selectInput("DN", "DN", choices = unique(df1$DN)),
                     
                     column(5,
                            fluidRow(
                              h3("Total"),
                              verbatimTextOutput("Ex1"))
                     ))
              
    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  d<- reactive({
    df1 %>%filter(DN == input$DN) 
  })
  
  output$Ex1 <- renderPrint({
    dataset <-d()
    Int <-mean(dataset$Intensity[dataset$DN == input$DN], na.rm=TRUE)
    Int  
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```